# How can I build and test with Bazel automatically when I save a file?

Tags: bazel

I am using [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) to build my project. Today, I have to run `bazel build` via the command line to trigger my build.
Is there a way to automatically trigger this when my source files change?

Answer (score 2):

[Bazel watcher](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-watcher) is a tool for building Bazel targets when source files change.

Once installed, you then use `ibazel` instead of `bazel` (example: `ibazel build //path/to/my:target`) and it will watch your files and rebuild the target when they are changed.

Bazel watcher supports `build`, `test`, and `run`